# One year suspension for a new contributor to "cool down"?

Tags: discussion, moderation, suspension

<sub>**EDIT**  December 20, 2019</sub>
<sub>I decided to undelete the question because users, old and new, had better be aware of the suspension penalties.</sub>

---

A new contributor was recently suspended for twelve months in order to "cool down".

There's no point in me posting the user's name or the question where this lively debate took place. Nearly all the comments have been deleted in any case.

In all fairness, the user was stubborn and sometimes borderline rude in their replies. In one instance, the user considered my suggestions and Janus Bahs Jacquet's observations to be patronizing and condescending, despite clarifying our positions he persisted and we both "left" the scene of battle. However, when I returned a few hours later, I saw their reputation had been reduced to 1  wherein I automatically suspected, *a week's suspension*. Instead, the suspension was for a year.

Not having the diamond next to my name–so I have no way of knowing–I believe this is the user's first suspension.  Although the user's attitude did deserve a warning and perhaps also a penalty, isn't one year a bit too much?

May I ask whether this was the user's first suspension? If so, why was such a severe penalty exacted on them, a *new contributor* whose only account, as far as I can tell, is on EL&U?

Comment: The user in question had already been suspended once, I think for one month.

Comment: Ahhh, that explains it. Thanks for telling me @user240918

Comment: My  impression is that the user has a "too personal approach" to the usage and meaning of words.  They tend to stubbornly reject  evidence and they appear to be looking for nuances of meaning that are hard to substantate. I suggested SE Writers.

Comment: @user240918 yes, I remember you giving that bit of advice. Well, I was concerned it was the user's first suspension, it wasn't. No need to go any further.

Comment: Without divulging specifics about this case, I can tell you the usual practice network-wide is 7 days suspension for the first serious issue, 30 days, for the second, and 365 days for the third. And we often warn before the first suspension.

Comment: Maybe instead of *vivacious* you meant *spirited* or *vigorous*?

Comment: I meant lively @aparente001 but it no longer matters. You can edit it if you want.

Comment: Sure.  I just like hearing the sound of your voice.  I miss you over at Meta.  And it's not just you.  I'm seeing rep=1 all over the place and I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I can tell you that I was suspended for one year from the French site just because I was argumentative. I was not rude, insulting or nasty. I did not make personal remarks. I think the mods just got tired and were unwilling to say anything to the native French speakers. I also detected a certain Canadian bias, I am sad to say... It was, in my view, completely unfair. And no discussion was possible.

Comment: @Lambie the aim of the mods on Meta  is to quell dissenting (civilised!) opinions as far as possible, in the hope that things will return to normal sooner than later.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't understand. Are you being funny?

Comment: @Lambie I think I know how to be funny. I'm speaking about Stack Exchange Meta, not EL&U meta. You've missed out on all the fun that began in October (sarcasm).

Comment: @Mari-LouA I really meant that I wasn't sure if you were being funny. Now, I see. I forgot your understated Brit humo**u**r. :)No, I haven't missed the "fun" but I avoided the fray but did say it seemed so very obvious that the site was at fault and not Ms. M.  Actually, one of the French mods who suspended me for a full year resigned as mod from the French site due to what was done to Ms. M.